# Remove today´s data from my report in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, report, dax

I would like to ask if someone know how to remove today´s data from my report in powerBI. I need only yesterday´s and older data but I don´t know how to remove only today´s dynamically, for every new day. So tomorrow, I need remove only tomorrow´s data and let today´s data and older. I tried IF( [date] <> today(), [date], blank()) But this is not working, my whole report showing very inaccurate data. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a date table in your PowerBI Dataset?

Comment: Yes I have a date table